# $(a+b+c)^p-(a^p+b^p+c^p)$ is always divisible by...?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

$(a + b + c)^p - (a^p + b^p + c^p)$
is always divisible by

(a) $p - 1\quad$   (b) $a + b + c\quad$    ( c ) $p\quad$   ( d ) $p^2 - 1$

$p$ is prime

I am able to solve this by substituting values and by euler theorem by assuming $( a + b + c )$ are co prime with $p$.

But I am unable to solve it by expansion nothing is working

Comment: You need to look at [Freshman's dream][1].


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream

Comment: @BabakSorouh I don't know but why do ask the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a+b+c)^p-(a^p+b^p+c^p)=(a+b+c)^p-(a+b+c)-(a^p-a)-(b^p-b)-(c^p-c)$

Since $x^p-x$ is 0 mod $p$, the above is always divisible by $p$ whether or not $a+b+c$ and $p$ are co-prime!

So option (c) is true

(b) and (d) are ruled out by setting $a=1,b=c=2,p=3$

Comment: Please try to prove or disprove part (a) also!

Comment: How x^p - x is divisible by p , its is only when x and p are co prime

Comment: That's just group theory. Go modulo $p$. You then are in the multiplicative group modulo $p$, which has order $p-1$ so $x$ should have order dividing $p-1$ mod $p$, so that $x^{p-1}$ is 1 mod $p$ whenever $x$ is non-zero mod $p$. This implies $x^p$ is $x$ mod $p$ which is also true when $x$ is $0$ mod $p$

Comment: Part (a) can also be proved or disproved quite easily.

Comment: Put a = 1, b = 3 and c = 5 and p = 2

Comment: (a) is ruled out by $a=b=1$, $c=0$, $p=5$.

Answer (score 1):

Expansion will do it, along with information about divisibility of certain multinomial or binomial coefficients by $p$.

But it is much cleaner to use Fermat's Theorem, in the version that says $x^p\equiv x\pmod{p}$. This holds with **no** restrictions on $x$. So in particular you need not separate out the case where $a+b+c$ is divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 0):

$(a+b+c)^p=a^p+b^p+c^p+$ terms containing some ${p\choose k}$ where $1\leq k\leq p-1$. As we know, ${p\choose k}=\frac{p}{k} {p-1\choose k-1}$ and as $p$ is a prime so $k\nmid p$ (as $k\lt p$), therefore, $\frac{{p-1\choose k-1}}{k}$ is an integer and thus $p\mid {p\choose k}$ and hence $(a+b+c)^p-a^p+b^p+c^p=$ terms containing some ${p\choose k}$ which is divisible by $p$ for sure.